# react google charts animation

Tags: reactjs, google-visualization

I have placed the following in the options object parametre for a pie chart using the react-google-charts api

```
animation: {
    startup: true,
    easing: 'linear',
    duration: 1500,
}
```

however there is no animation, the pie just loads as before. Is there any other settings I need to use for this to work?

Comment: You may need to provide more information of your code to receive an answer. How does your component setup look like? But my quick guess, without having had a look at it, would be that you probably have'nt provided it two different conditions. The animation will probably occur when you redraw the chart.  Check out the reference pages: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation

Comment: google's pie chart does not support animation, see the chart at the bottom of the [animation - supported modifications](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation#supported-modifications) section...